# Unable to rerun macro after delete the row

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run a code to validate a column "K". If any cells in column "K" is Null then an error message should pop up and the cell should turn to red. I tried the following code and it is working. Following is my issue.
I run the macro. 
Macro detects the Null cell and pop up error msg.
I deleted the row with Null cell.
Run macro again.
Error msg pop up again. Last cell of column K turn into red eventhough that row doesnt have any data.

This is the code I am using

```
Sub Errormsg ()
count2 = Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
For n = 2 To count2
If Range("K" & n).Value = vbNullString Then
Range("K" & n).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
MsgBox "Error ! Null value "
Exit Sub
End If                  
Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: You need `count2 = Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row - 1`. Otherwise the `count2` is the last empty cell e.g. if B1:B5 have values than `count2` = 6 and you end up checking K6

Comment: Thanks Alex for the help. This is working . but I used 999moorem's solution as it co validate another columns. Thnks again

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another column (like an ID or something that is never going to blank) and use that in the IF statement too

```
Sub Errormsg ()
count2 = Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
For n = 2 To count2
    If Range("K" & n).Value = vbNullString AND Range("A" & n).Value <> "" Then
        Range("K" & n).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        MsgBox "Error ! Null value "
        Exit Sub
    End If                  
Next n
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code is also work the last row. Just remove last row from loop. It will OK.

```
Sub Errormsg ()

     count2 = Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

     For n = 2 To count2 - 1 'Just modify it

         If Range("C" & n).Value = vbNullString Then

             Range("C" & n).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

             MsgBox ("Error ! Null value ")

             Exit Sub

         End If

     Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas for the help. This is working . but I used 999moorem's solution as it co validate another columns. Thnks again